# Creating an album on a Page

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to post make a album and upload photos to a page on facebook that I have administrative rights to. It works using my facebook account's ID found on [Find my facebook ID](http://www.findmyfacebookid.com) but it doesn't work when I use my page's ID. This is my code for creating the album.

```
var facebookClient = new FacebookClient(Properties.Settings.Default.AccessToken);
        dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
        parameters.name = AlbumName;
        parameters.description = AlbumDescription;
        parameters.uid = AlbumOwnerID;
        var fbResult = facebookClient.Post(string.Format("/{0}/Albums", AlbumOwnerID), parameters);
```

And this is the error that I get.

[image: Invalid ID]

Comment: and which uid you use here? i think, that you must use `page_id` instead

Comment: Nope that's not it. I think it has something to do with looping the auth tokens that I receive. Will come back if I get any results.